# W3 Total Cache and Woocommerce with Storefront theme: product-categories cache is not updated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront, w3-total-cache, page-caching

I am using W3 Total Cache on a Woocommerce website with the default Storefront theme and I am experiencing dificulties with product category pages (listings of products belonging to one product category).

If I add a product to a category, I will see it updated on the page (since I am logged in as admin and the option to disable cache for admins is enabled).

However, if I use another browser as guest, I will not see the new products, but instead a cached page server by W3TC. Something is preventing the cache plugin to "see" that the product category page was updated and therefore the need to regenerate the cache of that page.

To manually try to fix this:

I have tried clearing by browser cache and forcing the deletion of that page cache (under the admin bar > performance > purge current page) and it doesn't work.

Using "Purge All Caches" or "Purge Modules > Page Cache: All" does work, but the idea is just to purge the updated page and not all pages.

Any insights on solving this issue are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add those category pages in Performance>Page Cache>Advnaced. There you can find a lot of options, so you can choose the one that best suits you. Don’t cache the following pages or Never cache pages associated with these categories are one of the options that may help you with your issue.

Also, you can check on the page cache settings tab to be sure that the "Post terms pages" option is checked. There you can find so many options which might be helpful.
[image]

There is a tutorial on Woocomerce on how to set up W3TC with Wocommerce which you can [find here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/).
You can also find directions for your issue on W3TC blog [here](https://www.w3-edge.com/weblog/2014/08/w3-total-cache-and-https/).
I hope this helps

Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was to activate the "post terms page" checkbox in the Purge Policy: Page Cache.

Comment: Glad that I could help you.